# Something is wrong with the loop in Assembly x86_64

Tags: loops, assembly

I am trying to take multiple inputs in a loop and display them after that. The problem is with the first iteration of the loop. The first time while going through the loop it doesn't wait for user input but instead it directly goes to the second iteration as shown on the picture:

[image]

My code is here for the loop

```
section .text
computer_info:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    sub rsp, 300

    lea rbx, [computers]
    add QWORD [counter], 0
    .input_computers:
        mov rdi, QWORD echo_computer_name
        call print_string
        call print_nl
        call read_string
        mov  rsi, rax
        mov  rdi, rbx
        mov  rcx, 16
        rep movsb
        add  rbx, 16
        add  QWORD [counter], 1
        cmp  QWORD [counter], 2
        jne .input_computers

        mov QWORD [counter], 0
        sub rbx, rbx

    .display_loop:
        mov rdi, computers
        add rdi, rbx
        call print_string
        call print_nl
        add rbx, 16
        add QWORD [counter], 1
        cmp QWORD [counter], 2
        jne .display_loop

    add rsp, 300
    pop rbp
    ret
user_info:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    sub rsp, 32

    call main

    add rsp, 32
    pop rbp
    ret
search:
    call main
delete:
    call main

main:
; We have these three lines for compatability only
push rbp
mov rbp, rsp
sub rsp,32

mov rdi, QWORD echo_welcome
call print_string
call print_nl
mov rdi, QWORD echo_computer
call print_string
call print_nl
mov rdi, QWORD echo_user
call print_string
call print_nl
mov rdi, QWORD echo_search
call print_string
call print_nl
mov rdi, QWORD echo_delete
call print_string
call print_nl
call print_nl
mov rdi, QWORD echo_selection
call print_string
call read_int
mov rdi, rax
cmp rdi, 1
je computer_info
cmp rdi, 2
je user_info
cmp rdi, 3
je search
cmp rdi, 4
je delete

; and these lines are for compatability
add rsp, 32
pop rbp

ret
```

Comment: learn how to use a debugger, and see what happens after `call read_int`

Comment: for what I see, all these stackframes (`push rbp`, `mov rbp,rsp`, `sub rsp, <xx>` and `add rsp, <xx>`, `pop rbp`) are not needed. You don't use a single local variable in any of the functions

Comment: `je` is conditional jump, not call. Your whole "main" loop design doesn't make much sense, why do you ever return from main, if the program doesn't have any "exit" option? Shouldn't it loop infinitely? You should step over this in debugger and watch `rsp` and memory area around... and re-read the course notes or some stack tutorials **and** instruction descriptions [`call`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CALL.html) [`ret`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/RET.html), together with debugger view it should be somewhat easier to grasp.

Comment: Ok let me try the debugger